# Game Development at iOS+Android Platform : Template Engine for UI

Tags: android, xcode

We have broken down our game development process to

- UI Programming
- Core Game Programming
- Particle Effect Programming

UI will be created by a group of programmers and those UI will be used at Core Game Programming.

For example, at web applications, there are several template engine available, for example `Smarty`.

- Is there any Template engine for UI for Game Development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's such a thing as a "Game UI Tempalte-Only Engine". Really your best bet for getting IOS and Android dev in one go + out of the box UI widgets (such as text , buttons, etc) is [Unity](http://unity3d.com/). I find it a lot easier than the run of the mill "Open GL Text libraries" and such:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/gui-Basics.html

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't know what you mean by "Template engine for UI for Game Development" but I think CocosBuilder + cocos2d-x/cocos2d-JavaScript bindings is a free yet capable alternative for cross platform game GUI development. It is trivial to make menus, text, backgrounds, menu animations... etc with CocosBuilder.